# Get 2 or many coming fridays dates from current date c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, angular, webforms

I am working on a module (scheduler).
If I add scheduler and I select 2 or many tuesdays from current date to schedule my task. And It will show my task on scheduler for coming 2 or many tuesdays. How can I code this.

To get 2 or many tuesdays from current date. C# or jquery

I have seen many codes but these are not fulfilling my condition.

`Var date = new date()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
        DateTime dtFrom = DateTime.Today;  // any starting date

        int NextWeekDay = 5; // 1=Sun, 7=sun, so look for Friday's
        int HowMany = 3;     // how many to get

        NextWeekDay = NextWeekDay - (int)dtFrom.DayOfWeek;
        if (NextWeekDay < 0)
            NextWeekDay += 7;

        DateTime dtStart = dtFrom.AddDays(NextWeekDay);
        for (int i=0; i < HowMany; i++)
        {
            DateTime MyDate = dtStart.AddDays(i * 7);
            Debug.Print(MyDate.ToLongDateString());
        }
```

output:

```
Friday, December 9, 2022
Friday, December 16, 2022
Friday, December 23, 2022
```

So, today is Saturday Dec 3rd, and I count/include today if the requested starting date is same date.